# PHP CSV File Generate , How change csv column width

Tags: php, excel, csv

I am trying to generate few reports using PHP CSV. When I open output csv file in  MS Excel 2007 , that files columns shrink and not showing all content on that columns, Is there any method to exact column width using PHP?

Current Output:
[image]

Required Output:

[image]

Comment: this is surely the opening program and not php or csv related as they are doing the job -can you clarify what application you are using and re categorise the question

Comment: @ShaunHare Iam open file using MS excel 2007

Comment: this may help you -- 
http://superuser.com/questions/128272/in-excel-2007-how-to-give-height-auto-to-show-all-text-inside-cell-by-default-li

Comment: @MShahzadKhan Thank you for your output, but I am searching a PHP code to do it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is an excel question then

To automatically change the column width so it fits the widest entry, use AutoFit. Double-click the boundary on the right side of the column heading or choose Format→AutoFit Column Width on the Home tab.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your feedback but, we can't say to non technical person to double click the boundary line before reads the content. so I am searching php code to do dynamically.

Comment: Joel - You can't do this dynamically with a CSV file, because a CSV file cannot contain any format information (such as column widths) but only data - if you need formatting, you need a file format that __does__ support formatting as well, such as Excel BIFF (xls) or OfficeOpenXML (xlsx)